# Clear cache and cookies from Android browser

Tags: android, cookies, browser, appauth

I am looking for a way to clear the cache/cookies of Chrome using a code. My app is using appAuth for security purpose. Unfortunately AppAuth doesn't work using WebView but use the default browser on your device.

When I logout, even if I end the sessions, the cache/cookies are not cleared. So the next time I login, AppAuth session will use the cookies stored in Chrome and not ask again for credentials until the token expired. I am trying to clear cache and cookies to prevent this. When doing it, it works as I expect.

I used this

```
ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();

if(Browser.canClearHistory(cR)){
    Browser.clearHistory(cR);
    Browser.clearSearches(cR);
}
```

but it's not working `cleanClearHistory` and other are not present.

Any idea ?

Comment: I hope that what you want is not possible, as that would suggest some particularly poor decisions on the part of Chrome's developers. Not to mention the fact that Chrome is not the default browser on all Android devices. Have you tried using Chrome Custom Tabs?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using Chrome Custom tabs

Comment: Your question says otherwise. You might consider adding a [mcve] showing your code.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's an example I found and add it here to avoid people pointing to this solution which is no more working